# Scripting C# in wpf desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, scripting

Was looking for some advice as I am totally new to scripting. We have a desktop application written in C# on the .net framework and using a sqlite data base. 
We want to implement scripting for testing the program for basic testing initially and later full scenarios.

Ideally would like to use C# for the scripting and using visual studio (since I would be more familiar with those two).

Any advice/ guidance on where to start/ books to read etc would be very much appreciated

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is you are trying to use c# to script your testing. If that's the case you can use a unit testing project in visual studio. If you search around for introduction to unit testing you can find more information. Here is a link to a walkthrough on msdn.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx